# What is the actual nuance of the verb に映る

Tags: verbs, adverbs, reading-comprehension

> この通路の先で行われてることを考えると楽しいとは言えないけど

Which is about "If I think of what happens ahead of this passage, I can't say it's "fun"."

To which then the other character replies

> おっしゃる通り
>
> むしろ　侮辱的にすら映る

Going from context.. I suppose it may be something like "The vulgarity is reflected". I assume "すら" here is just "even" but I'm struggling with 侮辱的に映る. Most of google hits seem to be about "魅力的に映る" which seems to be akin to "Looking very tempting"?

Comment: Is "ことと考える" actually "ことを考える"?

Comment: を、 sorry. My mistake.

Comment: One of the meanings of 映る is 人の目にある印象を与える (this from goo's dictionary), so I think that is what you have here. And 侮辱 is 'insult, slight'.

Answer (score 2):

～に映る is a phrase that means "to appear (in someone's eyes) as ～" or "to strike someone as ～". One of the basic meanings of 映る is "(for an image) to be projected (on a screen, film, retina, etc)".

> むしろ侮辱的にすら映る。
> It even strikes me as insulting.

Its usage is the same as ～に聞こえる or ～に見える. You can use the ku-form of an i-adjective, too. For example, 彼女の姿は彼の目には悲しく映った translates to "Her figure appeared sad in his eyes".